# .py files can't be run directly after installing Python 3.6, Windows

Tags: python, python-3.x

I installed Python 3.6, then uninstalled Python 3.4.

I used to be able to double-click `.py` files in window explorer to run my scripts directly, or by simply typing in command prompt `main.py`. A console window would open and my script would do it's thing.

After the installation-uninstallation, however, I can no longer do this. Double-clicking `.py` or simply typing `main.py` opens Microsoft Visual Studio 2015's create account window.

---

Right-clicking the `.py` file and using 'open with', I have tried navigating to my Python 3.6 installation path and opening the script with both `python.exe` and `pythonw.exe`. The former opens a console window very briefly, for a split second, and then closes itself. The latter does nothing.

My installation is python-3.6.0-amd64. I have tried the repair option as well as modify option in the installation/setup file I downloaded. Under advanced options in modify option in the setup file, 'associate files with Python (requires the py launcher) is checked.

Following some relevant advice on another stack overflow thread, I ran `assoc` and `ftype` setting commands in the windows command prompt with administrative privileges. Now:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>assoc .py .py=Python.File

C:\WINDOWS\system32>ftype Python.File Python.File=C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\pythonw.exe "%1" %*
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went to sleep, and came back to this question to give it another go.

...I forgot to put in a `time.sleep()`, so the script closed itself as soon as it ran, or an exception was called.

whew lads.